# GeoWebCache says Unable to find GridSet for "EPSG:3857"

Tags: geowebcache

When trying to use the EPSG 3857 (via EPSG:3857 in geowebcache.xml), we see log errors:

```
18:45:16 ERROR  [config.XMLGridSubset] - Unable to find GridSet for "EPSG:3857"
18:45:16 ERROR  [layer.AbstractTileLayer] - EPSG:3857 is not known by the GridSetBroker, skipping for layer my:test
```

Regardless of the error messages, it seems that GWC will do caching anyway.

What would be the correct way to use GeoWebCache for caching EPSG 3857-based WMS requests?

Comment: Does a gridset called epsg:3857 exist? what if you use EPSG:900913 instead?

Comment: @nmtoken: In the geowebcache.xml there is no such gridSet defined. Are there any defaults defined in GeoWebCache, e. g. 900913 that I can copy into the xml? As far as I remember we have already worked with 900913 and no such error messages occured (or we just ignored them, I'm not sure).

Comment: GWC that comes with GeoServer includes a EPSG:900913 gridset. 
 If you're creating from scratch perhaps you need~ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opengeospatial/2D-Tile-Matrix-Set/master/registry/xml/WebMercatorQuad.xml

Comment: Thank you. Actually, we already have a running standalone GeoServer and simply want to add the missing gridSet. I wonder where the gridSets are stored - is it possible to add your xml file or past its content somewhere? At least gridSets can be edited/copied/removed via GUI according to https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/gridsets.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try to create a new GridSet in the GeoServer/ GWC admin area, as documented here, that is exactly the link that you also mention in your comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/gridsets.html.

Go to GridSets > Create a new gridset, then add the required parameters and the desired zoom levels and save.

Then, to let GWC use this gridset for all your defined layers, go to Caching Defaults > Standard Cache Gridsets and add the newly defined gridset.

This should be everything to make the new gridset be used by your tiled queries.